# How to use openssl to do a anonymous DH connection

Tags: linux, security, openssl

Hi I am new to working with openssl, i am trying to implement anonymous Diffie Hellman connection using openssl.

The code server code looks some thing like this:

```
#include "openssl/err.h"
#include "openssl/ssl.h"
#include "openssl/dh.h"
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define FAIL -1
// Create the SSL socket and intialize the socket address structure
int OpenListener(int port) {
  int sd;
  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_port = htons(port);
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  if (bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
    perror("can't bind port");
    abort();
  }
  if (listen(sd, 10) != 0) {
    perror("Can't configure listening port");
    abort();
  }
  return sd;
}
int isRoot() {
  if (getuid() != 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
SSL_CTX *InitServerCTX(void) {
  SSL_METHOD *method;
  SSL_CTX *ctx;
  DH *dh_;
  int codes = 0;

  OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();     /* load & register all cryptos, etc. */
  SSL_load_error_strings();         /* load all error messages */
  method = TLSv1_2_server_method(); /* create new server-method instance */
  ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);        /* create new context from method */
  if (ctx == NULL) {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
  }
  if (SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "ADH-AES256-SHA256") != 1) {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
  }

  dh_ = DH_new();
  if (dh_ == NULL) {
    printf ("Alloc for dh failed\n");
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
  }
  // Generate Parameters.
  if (!DH_generate_parameters_ex (dh_, 1024, DH_GENERATOR_5, NULL)) {
    printf ("Generate Parameters failed!!\n");
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
  }

  // Check if p and g parameters are safe to use.
  if (!DH_check (dh_, &codes)) {
    printf ("Cannot perform DH check\n");
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
  }
  if (codes) {
    printf ("DH codes: %x\n", codes);
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
  }

  if (!DH_generate_key (dh_)) {
    printf ("Failure in DH Generate key\n");
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
  }

  SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh(ctx, dh_);
  DH_free(dh_);

  return ctx;
}

void Servlet(SSL *ssl) /* Serve the connection -- threadable */
{
  char buf[1024] = {0};
  int sd, bytes;
  const char *ServerResponse = "<\Body>\
<Name>aticleworld.com</Name>\
<year>1.5</year>\
<BlogType>Embedede and c\c++<\BlogType>\
<Author>amlendra<Author>\
<\Body>";
  const char *cpValidMessage = "<Body>\
<UserName>aticle<UserName>\
<Password>123<Password>\
<\Body>";
  if (SSL_accept(ssl) == FAIL) /* do SSL-protocol accept */
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
  else {
    //ShowCerts(ssl);                          /* get any certificates */
    bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); /* get request */
    buf[bytes] = '\0';
    printf("Client msg: \"%s\"\n", buf);
    if (bytes > 0) {
      if (strcmp(cpValidMessage, buf) == 0) {
    SSL_write(ssl, ServerResponse, strlen(ServerResponse)); /* send reply */
      } else {
    SSL_write(ssl, "Invalid Message",
              strlen("Invalid Message")); /* send reply */
      }
    } else {
      ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }
  }
  sd = SSL_get_fd(ssl); /* get socket connection */
  SSL_free(ssl);        /* release SSL state */
  close(sd);            /* close connection */
}
int main(int count, char *Argc[]) {
  SSL_CTX *ctx;
  int server;
  char *portnum;
  // Only root user have the permsion to run the server
  if (!isRoot()) {
    printf("This program must be run as root/sudo user!!");
    exit(0);
  }
  if (count != 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s <portnum>\n", Argc[0]);
    exit(0);
  }
  // Initialize the SSL library
  SSL_library_init();
  portnum = Argc[1];
  ctx = InitServerCTX();                             /* initialize SSL */

  server = OpenListener(atoi(portnum));              /* create server socket */
  while (1) {
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(addr);
    SSL *ssl;
    int client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr *)&addr,
                    &len); /* accept connection as usual */
    printf("Connection: %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr),
       ntohs(addr.sin_port));
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);      /* get new SSL state with context */
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, client); /* set connection socket to SSL state */
    Servlet(ssl);            /* service connection */
  }
  close(server);     /* close server socket */
  SSL_CTX_free(ctx); /* release context */
}
```

The client program looks like this:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/dh.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define FAIL -1
int OpenConnection(const char *hostname, int port) {
  int sd;
  struct hostent *host;
  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  if ((host = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL) {
    perror(hostname);
    abort();
  }
  sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_port = htons(port);
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long *)(host->h_addr);
  printf ("Connecting....\n");
  if (connect(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
    close(sd);
    perror(hostname);
    abort();
  } else {
      printf ("Connected...\n");
  }
  return sd;
}
SSL_CTX *InitCTX(void) {
  SSL_METHOD *method;
  SSL_CTX *ctx;
  DH *dh_;
  int codes = 0;
  OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();     /* Load cryptos, et.al. */
  SSL_load_error_strings();         /* Bring in and register error messages */
  method = TLSv1_2_client_method(); /* Create new client-method instance */
  ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);        /* Create new context */
  if (ctx == NULL) {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
  }
    if (SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "ADH-AES256-SHA256") != 1) {
        printf("SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list failed\n");
        SSL_CTX_free (ctx);
        ctx = NULL;
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }

  dh_ = DH_new();
    if (dh_ == NULL) {
        printf ("Alloc for dh failed\n");
    }
    // Generate Parameters.
    if (!DH_generate_parameters_ex (dh_, 1024, DH_GENERATOR_5, NULL)) {
        printf ("Generate Parameters failed!!\n");
    }
    // Check if p and g parameters are safe to use.
    if (!DH_check (dh_, &codes)) {
        printf ("Cannot perform DH check\n");
    }
    if (codes) {
        printf ("DH codes: %x\n", codes);
    }

    if (!DH_generate_key (dh_)) {
        printf ("Failure in DH Generate key\n");
        //retVal = false;
        //break;
    }

    SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh(ctx, dh_);
    DH_free(dh_);

  return ctx;
}
void ShowCerts(SSL *ssl) {
  X509 *cert;
  char *line;
  cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); /* get the server's certificate */
  if (cert != NULL) {
    printf("Server certificates:\n");
    line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
    printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
    free(line); /* free the malloc'ed string */
    line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
    printf("Issuer: %s\n", line);
    free(line);      /* free the malloc'ed string */
    X509_free(cert); /* free the malloc'ed certificate copy */
  } else
    printf("Info: No client certificates configured.\n");
}
int main(int count, char *strings[]) {
  SSL_CTX *ctx;
  int server;
  SSL *ssl;
  char buf[1024];
  char acClientRequest[1024] = {0};
  int bytes;
  char *hostname, *portnum;
  if (count != 3) {
    printf("usage: %s <hostname> <portnum>\n", strings[0]);
    exit(0);
  }
  SSL_library_init();
  hostname = strings[1];
  portnum = strings[2];
  ctx = InitCTX();
  server = OpenConnection(hostname, atoi(portnum));
  ssl = SSL_new(ctx);           /* create new SSL connection state */
  SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);      /* attach the socket descriptor */
  printf ("Before connect\n");
  if (SSL_connect(ssl) == FAIL) /* perform the connection */
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
  else {
    char acUsername[16] = {0};
    char acPassword[16] = {0};
    const char *cpRequestMessage = "<Body>\
<UserName>%s<UserName>\
<Password>%s<Password>\
<\Body>";
    printf("Enter the User Name : ");
    scanf("%s", acUsername);
    printf("\n\nEnter the Password : ");
    scanf("%s", acPassword);
    sprintf(acClientRequest, cpRequestMessage, acUsername,
        acPassword); /* construct reply */
    printf("\n\nConnected with %s encryption\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));
    ShowCerts(ssl); /* get any certs */
    SSL_write(ssl, acClientRequest,
          strlen(acClientRequest));      /* encrypt & send message */
    bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); /* get reply & decrypt */
    buf[bytes] = 0;
    printf("Received: \"%s\"\n", buf);
    SSL_free(ssl); /* release connection state */
  }
  close(server);     /* close socket */
  SSL_CTX_free(ctx); /* release context */
  return 0;
}
```

When i compile and execute this code i get the following error:

server side:

> 140093403805344:error:140940E5:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:996:

client side error:

> 140134052299200:error:141640B5:SSL routines:tls_construct_client_hello:no ciphers available:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:800:

Can any help me out on how to establish a connection with Anonymous DH?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: You see, few people here might be willing to look into hundreds of lines of C code. Beyond that, you should at least make it really clear what the two lines giving the error contain.